# Expression Tree with chained string methods

Tags: c#, lambda

I have created a predicate that looks like:

```
p.Name.Contains("Saw")
```

and I have the following code that works:

```
    private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildContainsPredicate<T>(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof (T).GetProperty(propertyName);

        // ListOfProducts.Where(p => p.Contains(propertyValue))
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

        MemberExpression memberExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(pe, propertyInfo);
        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof (string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] {typeof (string)});
        ConstantExpression constantExpression = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));

        // Predicate Body - p.Name.Contains("Saw")
        Expression call = Expression.Call(memberExpression, methodInfo, constantExpression);

        Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, pe);
        return lambda;
    }
```

But I want to change the predicate to:

```
p.Name.ToLower().Contains("Saw")
```

and I'm coming up blank.  I know that I have to add something somewhere where the MethodInfo is defined.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Add the method call to the `ToLower` method, just like you have the method call for the `Contains` method.  It's basically the same process, just get the `MethodInfo` and call `Expression.Call`.

Comment: Incidentally, `p.Name.ToLower().Contains("Saw")` will always return false.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Well, unless the current culture is something rather insensible that doesn't actually do what you think it should do (like, for example, considering `"S"` to be a lower case letter).

Comment: @Servy, thank you.  That was a lot easier than I thought.  I just needed another set of eyes.

Comment: @coson Expressions are *super* scary and intimidating, but when you get over that and take the time to actually try to see what they're doing, they're not so bad.  If you've found a solution feel free to post it as an answer, rather than just editing the question to say you found one.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than constructing the *entire* expression manually just because one tiny little piece is dynamic, you can use a regular lambda to define all of the contents that are in fact static, and then just replace the little bit that isn't.

Specifically, the general strategy you can use is to have a lambda with a parameter representing your little dynamic bit, and then using it in a regular lambda, and then replace all instances of that parameter with your dynamically constructed expression:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildContainsPredicate<T>(
    string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    Expression<Func<string, bool>> e = s => s.ToLower().Contains(propertyValue);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
    var body = e.Body.Replace(e.Parameters[0], property);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
}
```

This not only simplifies your original code, but makes other changes to this static code as easy as editing any regular old C# code, rather than requiring all of the expression manipulation, and the complexity (and loss of static typing) that comes along with it.

This solution uses the following method to replace all instances of one expression with another:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

---

Another approach, allowing things to be even more high level, is to write a `Compose` method that lets you compose expressions easily.  Conceptually we'll have two lambdas, and we want to create a lambda that represents invoking one and passing its result to the other, and then it returning the result:

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Compose<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

This uses more or less the same strategy that we used above, but it generalizes it instead of special casing it to your specific expressions.

We then have one remaining helper method to make before putting the pieces together; creating a method that represents accessing a property as defined by the string name of the property:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, string>> MemberSelector<T>(string propertyName)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyName);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(body, param);
}
```

Using these two helper methods (that aren't dependent on any particular situation), we can now construct the lambda that we want *without any custom built expression manipulation*:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildContainsPredicate<T>(
    string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    return MemberSelector<T>(propertyName)
        .Compose(prop => prop.ToLower().Contains(propertyValue));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the expression for the `ToLower`method, then use it in the `Contains` expression

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildContainsPredicate<T>(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof (T).GetProperty(propertyName);

    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

    MemberExpression memberExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(pe, propertyInfo);

    //ToLower expression
    MethodInfo toLowerMethodInfo = typeof (string).GetMethod("ToLower", new Type[]{});
    Expression toLowerCall = Expression.Call(memberExpression, toLowerMethodInfo);


    MethodInfo containsMethodInfo = typeof (string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] {typeof (string)});
    ConstantExpression constantExpression = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));

    // Pass ToLowerCall to  
    Expression call = Expression.Call(toLowerCall, containsMethodInfo, constantExpression);

    Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, pe);
    return lambda;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With respect to Andre's answer, which is essentially what I came up after Servy's initial comment, I wanted to post what I came up with:

```
    private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildContainsPredicate<T>(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof (T).GetProperty(propertyName);

        // ListOfProducts.Where(p => p.Contains(propertyValue))
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

        MemberExpression memberExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(pe, propertyInfo);
        // Thanks to Servy's suggestion
        Expression toLowerExpression = Expression.Call(memberExpression, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes));

        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof (string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] {typeof (string)});
        ConstantExpression constantExpression = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));

        // Predicate Body - p.Name.Contains("Saw")
        Expression call = Expression.Call(toLowerExpression, methodInfo, constantExpression);

        Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, pe);
        return lambda;
    }
```